# Etymology and meaning of "navy file"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I've been reading Heinlein's *Starship Troopers* in which the crews of the starships are referred to by the Mobile Infantry as "Navy files". This appears to be an affectionately derisory term. I was wondering, is this name used by real members of the army or marines to refer to navy people, and if so, what it means?

Consulting the dictionary [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/file) suggests it might mean *a line of persons or things arranged one behind another*, or possibly

> Military .
>   a.
>   a person in front of or behind another in a military formation.
>   b.
>   one step on a promotion list.

I'm also guessing that this is an American or pseudo-American term as I'd think on the right-hand side of the pond the navy would more likely be referred to as the *[Andrew](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-and1.htm)*.

Comment: I'd be nice to see an example, to see how Heinlein uses the expression in a sentence or paragraph.

Comment: @J.R., sorry, but I'm damned if I can find the book. It should be near the top of the heap, as I read it recently, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It most likely refers specifically to enlisted Navy personnel as opposed to officers, as in *[rank and file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_and_file)*.

Comment: "Rank and file" refers to a physical distribution of personnel. Ranks are soldiers lined up abreast, and files are soldiers lined up one behind another. Put the two together and you have a rectangular matrix, which is the customary way for enlisted personnel  to form up.

Answer (score 7):

This is why you don't stop at the first dictionary entry for a word.

> **file** <sup>2</sup>
>   *noun*
>   a line of people or things one behind another: *Plains Cree warriors riding in file down the slopes.*
>   • *Military* a small detachment of troops: *a file of English soldiers had ridden out from Perth.*

As you can see, the second entry here refers to a small group, or *detachment* of troops. It could also be used figuratively, especially as a *synecdoche*.